# Thread allocates memory, main process dies, what happens?

Tags: c, windows, memory-leaks

I am currently checking some code I have for memory leaks and this possibility struck me. Basically the pseudocode of what I'm doing is as follows,

```
void thread_func()
{
    char *fileName = malloc(someSize);
    /* Do something with fileName and other things */
    /* Enter a critical section */
    modify some global variables
    /*Exit critical section */
    free(fileName);
    return;
}
```

This function resides inside a DLL. The critical section and other things are initialized by a function which also resides inside the same DLL.

Now, my main process (which is a GUI) has a Cancel button. When the user clicks on that button, I call the DLL's cleanup function which happens to destroy my critical section.

I found that if the user clicks on Cancel during the execution of `thread_func()`, `thread_func()` will continue executing. When it reaches the critical section code, the critical section is invalid so I'm exiting right there. This is how I check for the cancel event inside the thread (since nothing else in my application can call the DLL's cleanup during the execution of `thread_func()`).

I cannot free `fileName` in `thread_func()` when I find that the critical section is invalid. My guess is because `thread_func()` has lost access to `fileName` since the main process exited. Is my guess right? My main question is, if I don't free `fileName` in this case, am I running the risk of a memory leak?

I have searched quite a bit for relevant information and haven't found anything so far. I would be extremely happy if someone can point me in the right direction/answer my question.

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

I decided to do some preliminary tests based on kol's suggestion (see answer below). I noticed something extremely strange which I just can't understand. Now my code is as follows:

```
void thread_func()
{
    char *fileName = malloc(someSize);
    /* Do something with fileName and other things */

    if(threadTerminated)
    {
        /* Cleanup */
        return;
    }

    /* Enter a critical section */
    modify some global variables
    /*Exit critical section */
    free(fileName);
    return;
}
```

And in my GUI, my OnCancel event handler is something like:

```
void OnCancel()
{
    threadTerminated = TRUE;
    WaitForMultipleObjects(noOfRunningThreads, threadHandles, TRUE, INFINITE);

    /* Other cleanup code */
}
```

I noticed that `WaitForMultipleObjects()` hangs indefinitely and my GUI becomes unresponsive. Shouldn't `WaitForMultipleObjects()` return quickly? Also, none of the cleanup happens in `thread_func()` if `threadTerminated` is `TRUE`.

Here's the strangest part IMO. When I remove `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, my code works just fine! All the cleanup happens, including the cleanup inside `thread_func()`. Can someone please help me understand this?

Please note that I'm checking for `threadTerminated` at only one point for now. I will check it at other important points later. I'm doing this just to see if I've understood what's happening.

Thanks again! Your answers are extremely helpful.

Comment: there are different types of memory leaks, in the case of a leak that does not grow it often is more of an inconvenience than an actual problem because the program is terminating anyway and the leak is not growing with time.

Comment: @claptrap, good point! But I want to erase any memory-leak scenario I find.

Comment: If the DLL's cleanup function is only called when the process is exiting, simply don't bother destroying the critical section.  The building is being demolished, so you don't need to sweep the floor!  If you need to handle the case where the DLL is being unloaded but the process will keep going, then you'll need to synchronize the cleanup with the thread as per the existing answers.  Keep in mind that, even in the absence of the critical section, you can't safely unload the DLL while a thread is still running code from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a process terminates, the OS will free all the memory it's been allocated, so not calling `free` on the allocated `fileName` won't cause any problem.

Anyway, I would change the code the following way:

1. Define a flag which indicates whether the thread should terminate: `bool terminated;`
2. When the process is about to terminate, set `terminated` to `true`, and [wait for the thread to terminate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2855/Waiting-for-a-thread-to-terminate).
3. In the thread function, check `terminated` at important points (for example, in the condition check of every loop). If `terminated` is `true`, stop everything done by the thread (for example, stop loops), release resources (for example, free memory allocated by the thread), and return.
4. After the thread terminated (that is, after the thread function returned), the process can release every remaining resource (for example, free memory allocated by the process, delete critical sections etc.) and exit.

This way you can avoid deleting critical sections before threads terminate, and you can free every allocated resource.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a bool. Use an event instead, so that the thread can sleep without producing pointless CPU load. See my answer.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure an event is better for this purpose. I mean there is no need to wait on this flag. The thread does its job, and at decision points, it checks the flag in order to decide whether it can proceed or should terminate in a graceful way. (The designers of Delphi used the same logic: the TThread class has a Terminated property, which is a Boolean.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This definitely seems like a possible solution to my problem. @Lundin, why wouldn't you recommend a bool? Just curious.

Comment: It is hard to tell what would be most appropriate for this particular case. A thread that is implemented as `while(!my_bool) do_work();` will consume 100% CPU. More info in the [link](http://www.flounder.com/badprogram.htm#Polling%20process) I posed in another comment.

Comment: @Lundin, Why would `while(!my_bool) do_work();` consume 100% CPU? If `my_bool` is `FALSE`, the while would exit right? Or am I completely missing something?

Comment: This won't consume 100% CPU: while (!terminated) { do_something(); Sleep(100); } Anyway, @Lundin you are right there are cases when waiting on an event object is better.

Comment: @Lundin I can show you similar texts for almost every API function, programming paradigm, language, etc.

Comment: I'd like to add that "When a process terminates, the OS will free all the memory it's been allocated" hides some truth. It really depends on what kind of resource we are talking of. You can allocate resources in the system that stay alive even after the process died. There are also operatingsystems which did not always handle this correctly (IIRC Windows 95 was one of them while the NT line was clean on that.)

Comment: @junix That sentence was about *memory*, not *resources* in general. To be precise, my sentence is true only for "usual" memory allocations, like the one in the question above. But it's definitely not true for *shared memory* allocations: shared memory can be accessed by multiple processes, so it cannot be deallocated by the OS automatically when one of the processes terminate. It can be deallocated only when every process which accessed it releases it by calling CloseHandle  - or when the OS is restarted.

Comment: @kol Thanks for clearification. As I said I just wanted to add this in order to avoid a wrong impression. Of course the sentence is not wrong.

Comment: @kol But Sleep() is pointless, when there are WaitFor functions. You introduce extra delays, slower context switches, overall worse real time performance, for no gain. The only reason you would use bool instead of an event is programmer laziness, which is a poor argument.

Comment: @Lundin "programmer laziness"... I really don't want to start a flame war. Please let's respect each other's experience. Anyway, I'm currently reading http://www.flounder.com/badprogram.htm and it's really interesting but I definitely do not agree with everything the author claims. You can find proper usage for almost every technique he mentions. There are situations when using a bool flag, calling Sleep, or even doing a "goto" is a good idea.

Comment: @kol Again you don't provide any rationale. _Why_ is it better to poll a bool in a loop with a Sleep _instead_ of using WaitForSingleObject? In case of VCL TThread, I would be very surprised if the Terminate() member function does not produce a event, which is then caught in the underlying implementation, which then translates it to a bool, for convenience. The whole business idea of VCL and Delphi/Builder is to hide away all API calls for the programmer. Don't assume that the interface it gives you equivalents the underlying implementation.

Comment: And yet another reason why bool is a bad idea, is that access to a bool is not guaranteed to be atomic, so you cannot use it for synchronization purposes.

Comment: @Lundin "you don't provide any rationale" I really don't understand what you want me to do. I do believe comments are not the proper place for discussing threading and synchronization problems in detail. In my answer I provided an easy-to-understand solution for the OP's problem. I could provide a more complicated solution, but I think my approach was enough to give the OP a starting point. If you don't think my solution works, you can *ask a specific SO question* about the comparison of advantages and disadvantages of a bool and an event for stopping a worker thread from the GUI thread.

Comment: @Lundin There is no polling in my solution. Imagine you wrote the code of the thread function. It does what it needs to do, to do its job. Then you add a bool which is checked at important points of the thread function. This bool is only used to ask the thread from the UI thread politely to stop. When the UI thread sets the bool to true, the worker thread will detect it somewhere in its code and will stop in a safe way. The UI thread simply waits for the worker thread to stop. I used this solution lots of times.

Comment: @Lundin Anyway, TThread's Terminate property is really a Boolean. There is no hidden waiting for an event.

Answer (score 1):

- Your thread should probably have some form of loop to be meaningful.
- When working with threads, you need to invent some way to gracefully terminate them in a safe, predictable manner.
- Critical sections are blunt, replace them with a mutex object that a thread can WaitFor.

The proper way to design this would be something like this:

```
HANDLE h_event_killthread = CreateEvent(...);
HANDLE h_mutex = CreateMutex(...);

...

void thread_func()
{
  const HANDLE h_array [] = 
  { 
    h_event_killthread,
    h_mutex 
  };

  ... // malloc etc

  bool time_to_die = false;

  while(!time_to_die)
  {
    DWORD wait_result;
    wait_result = WaitForMultipleObjects(2,         // wait for 2 handles
                                         h_array,   // in this array
                                         FALSE,     // wait for any handle
                                         INFINITE); // wait forever

    if(wait_result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) // h_event_killthread
    {
      time_to_die = true;
    }
    else if(wait_result == (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1)) //h_mutex
    {
      // we have the mutex
      // modify globals here
      ReleaseMutex(h_mutex);

      // do any other work that needs to be done, if meaningful
    }
  }

  cleanup();
}


// and then in the GUI:

void cancel_button ()
{
  ...
  SetEvent(h_event_killthread);
  WaitForSingleObject(the_thread, INFINITE);
  ...
}
```

**EDIT :**

Please have in mind that creating and deleting threads creates a lot of overhead code and may slow down the program. Unless they are worker threads, where the amount of work is significant compared to the overhead, consider to keep threads alive but asleep during the whole lifetime of the program.

Comment: I would strongly recommend [this](http://www.flounder.com/badprogram.htm) excellent reading.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This definitely seems like a much better design that what I have. What is `WAIT_OBJECT_0` though? Another question, why do you say critical sections are blunt? Also, that link looks quite interesting. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh never mind about `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, googled it. Another thing, currently only a small part of my application is multi-threaded, and it requires that all threads be started simultaneously (not my decision), otherwise I might have considered your suspend thread suggestion.

Comment: @AnishRam You will have to look up all these API functions in detail on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/). WAIT_OBJECT_0 is explained below WaitForMultipleObjects(). As for mutex versus critical section, I am far from an expert so I might be wrong, but I believe that a mutex can be used with WaitForMultipleObjects  function, while a critical section has the wait built-in in the EnterCriticalSection and thus can't be effectively combined with the "kill event" wait.

Comment: The whole reason why I used `EnterCriticalSection` rather than a mutex was [this](http://preshing.com/20111124/always-use-a-lightweight-mutex) link.

Comment: And I must say, that link you posted is an excellent read. Thank you very much

Comment: @AnishRam I think performance is a nonsense argument. The PC is not a RTOS and while you are using WaitFor and similar functions, you give away your time slice to other processes. The context switch time on a sluggish Windows system is not expressed in microseconds, you can probably be dang happy if it keeps <10ms. I'd also strongly question anyone who does benchmark tests on Windows with nano second accuracy, that's just complete nonsense. A modern Windows PC is [bloody awfully slow](http://hallicino.hubpages.com/hub/_86_Mac_Plus_Vs_07_AMD_DualCore_You_Wont_Believe_Who_Wins) and that's that.